# javascript {name: "demo1", franchise_id: null,number:"98765",status:"good"} how to fetch values expect null key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

In javascript object is like this

```
{name: "demo1", franchise_id: null, number:"98765", status:"good"}
```

how to fetch values expect null key value if key value empty should not fetch

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: for hint use object.values and array filter method to resolve this issue.

Comment: so, you don't want that whole object, or just the key with a null value?

Comment: So you're wanting only the values that are not null? Your question wording is very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) with [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get the desired result

- [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) turns a multidimensional array into an object
- [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) does the opposite, it turns an object into a multidimensional array
- [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) keeps all items in the array where the expression returns true and removes all items where it returns false

```js
const obj = { name: "demo1", franchise_id: null, number: "98765", status: "good" };
 
const result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([_, value]) => value !== null));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way.

```
var obj = {name: "demo1", franchise_id: null,number:"98765",status:"good"}


for(var propt in obj){
if (obj[propt] != null){
    console.log(propt + ': ' + obj[propt]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
obj={name: "demo1", franchise_id: null, number:"98765", status:"good"};
noNullObj=Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj)
  .reduce((acc, cv)=>{
    if(cv[1]!=null) acc.push(cv);
    return acc;
  },[])
);
console.log(noNullObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just filter the object you get with this function:

```
function filterObject(obj) {
    let filteredObject = {};
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
      if (key) filteredObject[key] = obj[key];
    });
    return filteredObject;
  }
```